# Create buttons programmatically with unique id

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, dynamic

I have created some buttons by first filling a class containing `get/set` methods and then using that info in `XAML`.

C#

```
List<MediaDetail> movies = new List<MediaDetail>();
...
...
MovieListView.ItemsSource = movies;
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Width="Auto">
            <Button Width="200" Height="300" Click="SelectMovie_Click" Name ="NEED THIS TO BE DYNAMIC">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>        
</Window.Resources>


<ListView Name="MovieListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = movies}" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="MovieListView_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

However the issue is, I need each button to have a unique id. I read elsewhere that this can't be done in `XAML` but I'm not sure how or where in my `C#` code to create these buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most flexible solution here would be to define a behavior:

```
public class UniqueNameBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        //assign unique name to the associated element, for example:
        AssociatedObject.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", null);
    }
}
```

In XAML, attach this behavior to any element:

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:UniqueNameBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

where `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` from `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly.